# Возникает ошибка: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: python

При запуске .py-скрипта возникает ошибка:

```
There was an error: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable.
```

Что я сделал не так? И как это исправить?

Comment: Посмотрите пож. сюда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined. Помоему аннологичная проблема

Comment: @Chubatiy я в английском не силён.

Comment: добавьте в начало скрипта строки `import matplotlib`
`matplotlib.use('Agg')`

Comment: @Chubatiy ImportError: No module named matplotlib, а если пытаюсь поставить его через pip install, то выбивает ошибку: `Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gDvDOS/matplotlib
`

Comment: Поставил модуль через `apt-get install python-matplotlib`, и снова получаю ошибку `no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable.`

Comment: попробуйте заменить `matplotlib.use('Agg')` на `matplotlib.use('GTK')`. У вам MacOS X?

Comment: @Chubatiy Debian 8 x64. Вставил GTK - всё равно та же ошибка.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, опишите, пожалуйста, непосредственно в вопросе, на какой системе вы запускаете этот скрипт, локальная ли это система (и запущена ли в ней *x-сессия*) или вы подключаетесь к ней удалённо (каким именно образом? с какой системы? запущена ли в ней *x-сессия*?)

Answer (score 3):

Скрипт пытается отобразить что-то на экран (например, GUI) и не может его найти (`$DISPLAY` переменная окружения не установлена правильно), например, потому что перенаправление X при заходе по ssh/запуске из cron не настроено или X сервер вообще не запущен/установлен.